# how to initialize an object which name is based on a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I have a bunch ob objects which I need to initialize according to the user input, all my objects are based on the same parent object and they are initialized in the same way. So right now I have something like:

```
if (response['type'] === 'texteditor') {
    tmpObj = new Texteditor(response['theID'], response['type'], response['devicesView'], templateID);
    responseMarkup[0].addEventListener("dblclick", tmpObj);
} else if (response['type'] === 'rectangle') {
    tmpObj = new Rectangule(response['theID'], response['type'], response['devicesView'], templateID);
} else if (response['type'] === 'image') {
    tmpObj = new MyImage(response['theID'], response['type'], response['devicesView'], templateID);
} else {
    tmpObj = new Elements(response['theID'], response['type'], response['devicesView'], templateID);
}
```

So because I will be coding more objects, I would like to do something like this:

```
tmpObj = new $[response['type']](response['theID'], response['type'], response['devicesView'], templateID);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use Eval to do this:

```
var objType = "Rectangule";
eval("tmpObj = new "+objType +"(response['theID'], response['type'], response['devicesView'], templateID);");
```

As the [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) says though:

> Don't use eval!
>
> eval() is a dangerous function, which executes the code it's passed
>   with the privileges of the caller. If you run eval() with a string
>   that could be affected by a malicious party, you may end up running
>   malicious code on the user's machine with the permissions of your
>   webpage / extension. More importantly, third party code can see the
>   scope in which eval() was invoked, which can lead to possible attacks
>   in ways of which the similar Function is not susceptible.

Answer (score 1):

If those classes are in global scope, try something like this:

```
var constructor = window[response['type']];
if( constructor ) {
    tmpObj = new constructor(response['theID'], response['type'], response['devices'], templateID);
}
```

If they aren't, I guess you'll have to go with evil `eval`, or to make it safer simply nest those classes in an object you have access to, like

```
var classes = {};

classes.Texteditor = function(){/* your code */};
classes.Rectangle  = function(){/* your code */};
...
```

Comment: it gave me this error: "Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function"

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary mapping the types:

```
var objmap = {
 'texteditor': TextEditor,
 ...
 };

var tmpObj = new objmap[objtype](...)
```